# I want to convert date format

Tags: java

I am using Java and I want to change my date format which will ignore initial zeros in date and time. Something like "2/2/2015 1:30 PM" instead of "02/02/2015 1:30PM"

Comment: I am actually getting date as 02/02/2015 01:30 Pm. I want to convert it to 2/2/2015 1:30 Pm

Comment: How does this have anything to do with Selenium?

Comment: Need to do validation...can you help using Java?

Comment: how can I convert 02/02/2015 01:30 Pm to 2/2/2015 1:30 PM using java and regular expression?

Comment: have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I tried using regular expression but its not succeed...it went something like 2/2/215......

Answer (score 1):

you can use a **SimpleDateFormat**

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d/MM/yyyy hh:mma");
String date = formatter.format(today);
```

see this link for the char codes:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thanks..but I am using selenium and I am getting something like 02/02/2015 01:30 Pm actually I want 2/2/2015 1:30 PM

Comment: @AjayShinde i edit my answer with the solution "d/MM/yyyy hh:mma"